# $facebook->api('/me') not giving the user data

Tags: php, facebook

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/facebook-php-sdk/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_MAIN_APP_API_ID,
  'secret' => FB_MAIN_APP_SECRET
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Above is the code I'm using to get the Facebook details for my application. In my localhost this is working fine and it gives my Facebook email, user id. After I upload this in to live server this function is not working and it's not giving my Facebook details. I checked on the Facebook app id and it is the correct one.

I cannot figure out why it's not working in live site since it is working in my localhost. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you setup correct Site url / canvas url in facebook developers dashboard?

Comment: Yes I did it. This code gives data when I'm running it through my localhost.

Comment: But, are you changing site url for "live site url" after upload?

Comment: For localhost there's a one Facebook app and for the live site there's another Facebook app. So I didn't change anything by manually.

Comment: Have you tried adding `error_reporting (E_ALL);` before `require`? There may be curl / ssl problem preventing facebook connection.

Comment: I added it but didn't give any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your app which your are using on server. So try the same app which you are using for your localhost and in login and logout url instead of localhost use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Example :

```
$session->fb_logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/path/to/logout"));
```

First check that what `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` showing. Just `print_r` the variable `$user_profile`.

Ex :

```
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($user_profile);
    exit;
```

if it showing blank then surely it will go in catch block. Then write following in catch block.

```
    print_r($e);
    exit;
```

Comment: I replace the appId with the localhost appId but still it is not working

Comment: try to print your error_log on Server and check what error it is showing

Comment: Can you please tell me how to print the error_log. Sorry for asking it.

Comment: I check on this $user = $facebook->getUser(); It is giving 0.

Comment: `try {
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 print_r($user_profile);
    exit;
}catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
 print_r($e);
    exit;
}` $facebook->getUser() outputs 0 so it's not going to get the detail. Can you guess why it's giving 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you have the correct URL in the configuration of your app in Facebook?

I have this piece of code to my FB apps and work properly, could you try it?

```
$session = $this->facebook->getUser();
if ($session) {
    $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    try {
        $data['uid'] = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $me = $this->facebook->api($session);
        $data['me'] = $me;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
} else {
    $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope' => 'publish_stream, user_about_me, email',
            'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR URL',
            'canvas' => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'display' => 'page',
        ));

}

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

$this->load->view('MY VIEW', $data);
```

Comment: Yes I checked on the url. It is correct. I replace the appId with the localhost appId but still it is not working.

Comment: I check on this `$user = $facebook->getUser();` It is giving 0.

Answer (score 0):

For geting the user id, user need to grant permission

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 echo $uid;

if($user_id){
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user_id = null;
  }
}else{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo("<br>login url=".$login_url);
};
```

After the user grant permission check the login_url, you may access user id.

Try this

Comment: I added this and it gives the login url. I do not have the user id.

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else just trace code line by line